# Update filepath name during "animation" render

Tags: python, scripting, customization, animation-nodes

I am using a python script to assign a StringProperty to the render output filepath name.

This StringProperty is being animated via Animation Nodes, and as such, on every frame, the string name changes. Using the script I have setup, I have set the render to "animation" because I am using the Current Frame data to for data modification purposes with Animation Nodes. As a result, I absolutely have to have an "image sequence" rendered.

I am setting the filepath name to this custom StringProperty within the code. Is there a way to make sure that the filepath name is updated whenever the render for the next frame starts? For example, when rendering frame one it's //parameter/#### + volume_1.02. This volume string changes to volume_0.97 on frame 2 but the image that is saved during rendering is not saved with the new string name attached.

See code below (note I have removed some unnecessary classes and irrelevant lines):

```
import bpy
import os
from bpy.props import FloatVectorProperty, StringProperty, PointerProperty, FloatProperty, BoolProperty
from bpy.types import Operator
from bpy.props import IntProperty, BoolProperty


class SceneProperties(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    @classmethod
    def register(cls):

        bpy.types.Object.scn_prop = PointerProperty(
            name="Scene Properties",
            description="Custom Scene Properties for Objects",
            type=cls,
            )

        cls.frame_num = IntProperty(name="Frame", default=1)
        cls.file_name = StringProperty(name="File Name", default="filename")
        file_name = cls.file_name

    @classmethod
    def unregister(cls):
        del bpy.types.Object.scn_prop


class UlriksProcessor(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Ulrik's Processor"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_utilities"

    bl_space_type = "PROPERTIES"
    bl_region_type = "WINDOW"
    bl_context = "object"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout       

        box = layout.box()
        row = box.row()
        row.prop(context.active_object.scn_prop, "file_name")
        row = box.row()
        row.operator("render.button", icon="RENDER_ANIMATION", text="RENDER")

output_path = scene.render.filepath

class RenderButton(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "render.button"
    bl_label = "Render"

    def execute(self, context):
        scn = context.scene
        file_name = context.object.scn_prop.file_name
        output_path = "//parameter/"  
        scn.render.filepath = os.path.join(output_path + '####' + file_name) 
        bpy.ops.render.render('INVOKE_DEFAULT', animation=True, write_still=False)
        scn.render.filepath = output_path

        return {'FINISHED'}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SceneProperties)
    bpy.utils.register_class(UlriksProcessor)
    bpy.utils.register_class(RenderButton)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SceneProperties)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(UlriksProcessor)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(RenderButton)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Setup an [app.handler](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.app.handlers.html#bpy.app.handlers.render_pre)

Comment: @sambler any ideas on how to go about doing that for this program here?